# При изменении контента страницы скачет футер

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На странице размещена новостная лента с табами для сортировки. По нажатию происходит изменение контента и при этом прыгает футер вот как это исправить
http://tsmir-alex.owstudio.ru/news.php

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать такой алгоритм:

1. При нажатии на таб делайте контейнер немного прозрачным (CSS свойство opacity). Это даст пользователю понять, что началось какое-то действие. Вообще хорошо бы накладывать вращающейся спинер.
2. Инициируйте ajax-запрос.
3. Если запрос успешно выполнился - перезапишите содержимое контейнера. Если вы используете jQuery, то это делается так $(".my-container").html("new-content-from-ajax").
4. Верните обратно значение opacity.

Comment: Проблема была в другом, но твой способ добавил красоты. Спасибо